# Macos specific bug in chrome. Works well in windows chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, macos-high-sierra

My html, css and js code works on my windows pc, but not mac.
What are the differences between mac version of chrome and windows version that could affect my code?

Here´s what I am trying to do:
https://jsfiddle.net/6vjq80xt/11/

(I recommend full-screening the run window)

The problem you see is that the text(option 1, option2, option3 and so on..) is kinda flickering. Why is that happening?

It seemed to work alright on my windows pc in chrome.

I am kinda unsure, but what I think is happening is that the computer is getting confused if `subnav_front` should be in front(in terms of z-axis) or if `subnav_back` should be in front.

That's what you see if you change the background-color of `subnav_back` to something other than blue.

But, then, why does it work on windows and not on mac osx?

In case jsfiddle doesn´t work, here´s the code:

```css
.subnav_section{
  margin: 15vw;
}

.subnav_container{

 margin: 0vw 1vw;                               
 /*perspective: 900px;*/
 display: inline-block;
}
.subnav{
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 15vw;
    width: 15vw;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 90px;
    transition: 1.5s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    translateZ: 0;
}    
.subnav:hover{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
   }
.subnav_front, .subnav_back{
 position: absolute;
 height: 15vw;
 width: 15vw;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.subnav_back{
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.subnav_images{
 height: 15vw;
 width: 15vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="subnav_section">
    <div class="subnav_container">
       <div class="subnav">
         <div class="subnav_front">
          <img class="subnav_images" src="http://catsatthestudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/12920541_1345368955489850_5587934409579916708_n-2-960x410.jpg" alt="Some_Image">
         </div>
         <div class="subnav_back">
          Option 1
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="subnav_container">
        <div class="subnav">
        <div class="subnav_front"><img class="subnav_images" src="Pics/brain.png" alt="Some_Image"></div>
        <div class="subnav_back">Option 2</div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="subnav_container">
        <div class="subnav">
        <div class="subnav_front"><img class="subnav_images" src="http://catsatthestudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/12920541_1345368955489850_5587934409579916708_n-2-960x410.jpgg" alt="Some_Image"></div>
        <div class="subnav_back"> Option 3</div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="subnav_container">
        <div class="subnav">
        <div class="subnav_front"><img class="subnav_images" src="Pics/brain.png" alt="Some_Image"></div>
        <div class="subnav_back"> Option 4</div>
        </div>
       </div>
         <div class="subnav_container">
        <div class="subnav">
        <div class="subnav_front"><img class="subnav_images" src="Pics/brain.png" alt="Some_Image"></div>
        <div class="subnav_back">Option  4</div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="subnav_container">
        <div class="subnav">
        <div class="subnav_front"><img class="subnav_images" src="http://catsatthestudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/12920541_1345368955489850_5587934409579916708_n-2-960x410.jpg" alt="Some_Image"></div>
        <div class="subnav_back"> Option 5</div>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: You may have some luck forcing GPU rendering by adding `.subnav { transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }`. And FYI; `translateZ: 0;` is not valid CSS.

Comment: Nope. Not working. Anyway, thanks for translateZ-thing.

Comment: It fixes the flickering for me. Does this example flicker in your browser? https://jsfiddle.net/6vjq80xt/15/

Comment: Did you increase the size of window, where you see the result? On the other side, you should see 'Option 1' (or Option2, Option3, so on...). And for me, no, I don´t see any difference. It still flickers.